# java-script input field validation

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a field called price, now how to validate this field by java script? It will take only integer value and dot. It may take decimal point or not.
   e.g 200,200.00 both are valid.
How shall I do that?

Comment: "only take characters" ... what would the other possibilities be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this.

Without the use of any 3rd party libraries i would recommend using regular expressions.

A possible pattern used to validate price would be

```
\d[\d\,\.]+
```

here is a tutorial on using regular expressions to validate fields in java-script

[Tutorial](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml)

Hope this helps